# Could you please assist me in my phpmyadmin login error despite correcting the .ini file

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am trying to login to phpmyadmin in wamp server but I cant despite using the same details I use to login to MySQL. I have tried to research as much as I could but none of the solutions I got seems to work for me. I am using phpmyadmin v4.92 and MySQL v8.018. Could someone please asssist me.

This is the error i am getting:

[image]

And this is the php ini file. This is the part everyone tells me to change but it doesn't seem to work at all even after `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';` to root

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will have a better experience here if you take the  [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question with the details needed to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Formatting improvements